# Create a different sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a sequence in the database that cannot be using sequence or identity.

There is a table in the database called File where all the files that users send in different areas of the system are stored.
It contains the id (primary key), name, type, folder, number, hash...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[File]
(
    FileId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    FileTypeId int NOT NULL,
    FileFolderId int NOT NULL,
    Number int NOT NULL,
    Hash nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    ...
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And then for each feature there is a table expanding the properties of the File table, an example is ContractFile.

It has the same id of the File table and with a few more fields and the id of the Contract table, creating the relation.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ContractFile
(
    FileId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ContractId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    ...
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So the filename should follow a pattern.

**050**#H4G5H4G244#*001*.pdf

**050**#H4G5H4G244#*002*.pdf

**060**#H4G5H4G244#*001*.pdf

The first 3 digits is a code that is in the FileType table.
The digits in the middle is the code in the Contract table.
And the last 3 is the sequence that was inserted.

Then it groups the string by the FileType and the Contract.

So I created a trigger in the ContractFile table for when inserting it get the biggest number for that FileType and for the Contract and add +1, setting the Number field of the File table.

Then the file name is updated (in the same trigger)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgContractFileInsert]
ON [dbo].[ContractFile]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE dbo.File
    SET Number = COALESCE(
                            (SELECT MAX(AR.Number)
                             FROM dbo.ContractFile NOA
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.File AR
                                    ON AR.FileId = NOA.FileId
                             WHERE NOA.ContractId = I.ContractId AND
                                    AR.FileTypeId = T.FileTypeId
                            ),
                         0) + 1
    FROM dbo.File T WITH (XLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Inserted I
            ON I.FileId = T.FileId
    WHERE T.Number IS NULL

    UPDATE dbo.File
    SET Name = dbo.fnFileName(AP.Code, NOB.Code, T.Numero, T.Name)
    FROM dbo.File T
            INNER JOIN Inserted I
            ON I.FileId = T.FileId
            INNER JOIN dbo.FileType AP
            ON AP.FileTypeId = T.FileTypeId
            INNER JOIN dbo.Contract NOB
            ON NOB.ContractId = I.ContractId
END
```

At first it works, but when we have a large volume being inserted, there is a deadlock.

And from what I'm seeing also when inserting more than one record will end up getting the same number, since the Inserted table will bring two records and the +1 is not checking this.

How could I solve this? What is the best way?
Avoid deadlock, will the sequence be correct even inserting more than one record at a time and have a good performance?

Comment: Deadlocks are often a symptom that query/index tuning is needed. Do you have any indexes on the tables other than the primary key (which should be included in your DDL)?

Comment: I have an index on the File table on the Number column.

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_File_Number] ON [dbo].[File] ([Number]) INCLUDE ([FileTypeId])

Comment: Do you actually have the primary and foreign keys declared? You could combine these two `UPDATE`s into one. And you're going to need `ROW_NUMBER` to solve the multiple row issue

Comment: Even doing it in a single call gives the same deadlock problem.